# Derivative of Log Confusion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, logarithms, partial-derivative

I am trying to take partial derivative of $\log(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

The derivative formula for $\log_ab$ is $$\frac 1{ln(a)*b}b'$$

When I solved the question I was unsure of whether to include ln(10) in the denominator so I checked some online calculators.
(in the second image I entered log but it changed to ln) 
[image]
[image]

What is the discrepancy?

Comment: Usually, $log$ just means natural logarithm in mathematical notation, as far as I am aware. So I wouldn't include $ln(10)$. If it were a different base, it's usually notated in a mathematical setting. In Electrical Engineering, where we might deal with $dB$, $log$ would probably mean base $10$. In a binary system, it might mean base $2$.

Comment: There is no discrepance. In the first situation it is computed the derivative of $\log_{10}$ and in the second one the derivative of $\ln=\log_{e}.$ Once you know the basis of the logarithm you will know the derivative.

Comment: @learning so derivative of a log without specifying a base would not need to include ln(10) because its the same meaning?

Comment: @mfl yea i just realized but i had put log and it was automatically changed to ln

Comment: That's how I usually work with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, log just means natural logarithm in mathematical notation, as far as I am aware. So I wouldn't include ln(10). If it were a different base, it's usually notated in a mathematical setting. In Electrical Engineering, where we might deal with dB, log would probably mean base 10. In a binary system, it might mean base 2.

-copypasted from learning's comment